# CSS alignment issues - Search box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my search button with my text input/search bar but cannot seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

The site can be seen here: http://www.computerpartsforsale.co.uk/Whois/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for debugging help. Please describe the issue clearly in your question, provide a concise example of your code, and show which solutions you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #search button {
    padding: 24px;
 }
```

Add this style.